# Enlarge the quick panel of sublime text

Tags: width, sublimetext2, panel

I am looking for a way to enlarge the quick panel (when you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then select **install Package**) because when I want to install a new package from the Package Control, I can't see the whole github link.

[image]

I thought the configuration was in a sublime-theme file but I can't find the property to make the width bigger.

In fact I am using the Phoenix theme so I created a Phoenix Dark.sublime-theme in my User folder and I tried different values for `quick_panel` playing with `padding` and `margin`. Nothing is correct.

```
[
    {
        "class": "quick_panel",
        "row_padding": [0, 2]
    },
    {
        "class": "quick_panel_row",
        "layer0.texture": "Theme - Phoenix/Phoenix Dark/quick-panel-row.png",
        "layer0.inner_margin": [2, 2, 2, 2]
    }
]
```

If this is not possible, maybe there is something to display the details of a package?

if someone have an idea?
Thnks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope sorry. I gave up. Waiting for some more flexibility maybe in a future release of ST2...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for the Github link, the [Package Control website](https://sublime.wbond.net) is a great resource. It's fully searchable (package name and short description), and each package's page presents a nice combination of data, including the README from Github/bitbucket, info on Sublime versions and platforms supported, installation statistics so you can see how popular a particular package is and when it was last updated, and links to the project's Issues page as well as a Gittip link in case you want to donate to support the author(s). I usually do all my research there first, then go to the Command Palette quick panel when I'm ready to install.